# How can we fetch the elements of the list of specific index?

Tags: python, list, indexing

I have a python list say

```
a= ['Sample Date', '4/21/2015', '10/14/2014', '9/16/2014', '7/10/2014', '8/11/2014', '8/3/2014', '7/20/2014', '7/6/2014', '8/11/2014', '8/11/2014', '8/11/2014']
```

and I have a list of indexes belongs to list a say

```
b=[5, 9, 10, 11].
```

what should be the code to get the following output

```
c= ['7/20/2014', '7/6/2014','7/20/2014', '7/6/2014']
```

Comment: How do the indexes in `b` relate to `a` to make `c`. I mean the 5th index in `a` is not '7/20/2014' its '8/11/2014'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a simple list comprehension

```
>>> a= ['Sample Date', '4/21/2015', '10/14/2014', '9/16/2014', '7/10/2014', '8/11/2014', '8/3/2014', '7/20/2014', '7/6/2014', '8/11/2014', '8/11/2014', '8/11/2014'] 
>>> b=[5, 9, 10, 11]
>>> [a[i-1] for i in b]
['7/10/2014', '7/6/2014', '8/11/2014', '8/11/2014']
```

Or

```
>>> [a[i] for i in b]
['8/11/2014', '8/11/2014', '8/11/2014', '8/11/2014']
```

If it is based from `0`th index

Answer (score 3):

[operator.itemgetter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html?highlight=itemgetter#operator.itemgetter)
does exactly this

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> a = ['Sample Date', '4/21/2015', '10/14/2014', '9/16/2014', '7/10/2014', '8/11/2014', '8/3/2014', '7/20/2014', '7/6/2014', '8/11/2014', '8/11/2014', '8/11/2014'] 
>>> getitems = itemgetter(5, 9, 10, 11)
>>> getitems(a)
('8/11/2014', '8/11/2014', '8/11/2014', '8/11/2014')
```

Comment: Can you show how the code will look like with the itemgetter?

Comment: Does this work in Python 2? I get this: NameError: name 'itemgetter' is not defined

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include the import line. Adding now.